# Loopback - Adding 'automatic methods' to both models for hasAndBelongsToMany relation

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using the Strongloop API Platform and more specifically Loopback to create an api.

I have added a hasAndBelongsToMany relation to **Model1** with **Model2**.

Works great, **Model1** now has a bunch of methods added to it for different querying and CRUD operations.

I would now like to have these same methods added to **Model2** so I can query and perform CRUD operations the other way.

Is this easily done out of the box using Loopback?

If not the only options I feel I have are:

1. Create another hasAndBelongsToMany relation the other way which would result in another table being created and a lot of duplicate data.
2. Create custom methods for **Model2** which access the methods from **Model1** and will essentially do the same as these automatically generated methods.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your option 1 - create hasAndBelongsToMany relation for Model2 with Model1. Don't worry, another table will not be created. Loopback is smart enough to not do so ;)

Comment: I believe you are suggesting option 1. I have tried this to find out that loopback is not that smart. It creates 2 relationship tables (one for each relation)

Comment: Ups my bad. Turns out loopback indeed uses only one table. In my case, another table was created before I define the relationship only in one of the model. After I defined the relationships in both models, that table was actually not used. I will upvote your answer again once you modify it. Thanks.

Comment: @YohanesGultom you're right. I somehow wrote option 2, but should be option 1.